# Finding device IP J2ME

Tags: java-me

I am trying to connect 2 devices together using a datagram connection but so far it only works over localhost so I need to find the IP of the device to open the connection but I don't know how to do this. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_obtain_mobile_IP_address_in_J2ME